# Text in Text Widget (tkinter) doesn't update

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working with Tkinter, trying to make a text widget that can update its value every second, but I don't know why it doesn't work as expected. I hard-coded the text widget position @@

- Environment: pipenv, version 2021.11.23. Python 3.9 (32bit)
- Code:

```py
    self.text = tk.Text(self.root, height=25, width=97)
    self.text.configure(state='disabled')
    self.text.place(x = 10, y = 150)
    
    def update_text(self):
        self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.text.insert(tk.END, str(self.i))
        self.i += 1
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_text)
    
    self.update_text()
    self.root.mainloop()
```

- Expected output: text widget show a number increasing by 1 every second.
- What happened instead: nothing appears on the text widget.
- I tried to insert some text right after calling the configure() function and the number did appear on the screen.

Comment: why not use a `Label`?

Comment: @EliHarold I actually need to display a wall of text but not a single number so I choose the Text widget instead. Do I miss anything since I'm really new to Tkinter?

Comment: Because the text widget is disabled.

Comment: You can't insert text when the widget is disabled. You can enable the widget right before inserting the text and then disable it again after you insert.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh, I really didn't notice it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Setting the text widget's state to 'normal' solved the problem.